# Cannot change color of UML state in jointjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, jointjs

I'm new to jointjs and I'm trying to change the color of UML state diagram graph by using the following command:

```
graph.getElements()[4].attributes.attrs[".uml-state-body"]["fill"] = "#ff0000";
```

But it is not changing the color of the state.

Answer (score 1):

use the API method instead:

graph.getElements()[4].attr('.uml-state-body/fill', '#ff0000')

http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.0/joint.html#dia.Element.prototype.attr

Comment: thanks it worked...Can you please upvote my question ?